# Changing field instance display settings for view_mode

Tags: 7, users

#### Background

In the user.module file in `user_build_content()`, there is a line that adds fields for a given view_mode:

```
$account->content += field_attach_view('user', $account, $view_mode, $langcode);
```

The documentation for the `field_attach_view()` function says

> Each field is displayed according to the display options specified in the
>    $instance definition for the given $view_mode.

Digging further, I find that the instance definitions are loaded/cached using `FieldInfo->getBundleInstances()`, which loads them from the `field_config_instance` table in the database in `field_read_instances()`.

#### Question

I have some custom user fields already being displayed for the 'teaser' view_mode, to the exclusion of others, and I cannot find where this is coming from since no hook appears to do it in the code.

How do I change the display settings of a field for a specific view_mode? Is there a place to do this in the field UI somewhere?

**Edit:** I found the defaults coming from `hook_field_default_field_instances()`, which were exported into a module using the Features module. Can anyone tell me where I can change them in the UI in order to re-export the feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me so long to find. Account Settings -> Manage Display

```
admin/config/people/accounts/display/teaser
```